# Datatables.net ajax.reload(): avoid rebuilding DOM if not necessary

Tags: ajax, datatables-1.10

I'm using [DataTables.Net JS component](https://www.datatables.net/examples/index) for rendering data from server (reloading is performed on timeout).

Is there a way to avoid rebuilding `<TR>`s on ajax.reload(), if rows are not actually changed? I don't want my custom classes for `<TR>`s to disappear.

**UPDATE**

Here's how I initialize the component:

```js
myTable = $('#myTable').dataTable(
{
    'ajax':
    {
        'url': 'data', // Something like http://myserver/data
        'dataSrc': '' // All data go right in the root of JSON.
    }
...
```

My custom classes are such as `.selected` according to the 'Multiple selection' example on the DataTable site.

Regards,

Comment: How do you initialise the dataTable and add custom classes to the rows in the first place ..?

Comment: @davidkonrad I've updated the question, please take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunetely dataTables empties the table on each `reload()`. So excluding already existisng rows in a `dataSrc` callback would not be possible.

But you can do the AJAX yourself, and insert new rows "manually" if they not already exists. I assume you are using JSON datasource so you can compare existing rows with new rows using `JSON.stringify`.

Here is an example (includes select) using `setInterval` :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   select : true, 
   columns : [ 
     { "data" : "id" },
     { "data" : "name" }, 
     { "data" : "lat" }, 
     { "data" : "lon" }]
});

function loadData() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/14t4g', function(json) {
        function rowExists(item) {
            for (var i=0;i<table.data().length;i++) {
                if (JSON.stringify(table.row(i).data()) == JSON.stringify(item)) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }    
        json.forEach(function(item) {
           if (!rowExists(item)) {
              table.row.add(item).draw();
           } else {
              console.log('row already exists', item);
           }     
        })
    });
}    

var test = setInterval(function() {
    loadData()
}, 1000);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qseeeu43/**